# How to normalize data for varying number of observations?

Tags: statistical-significance, normalization

[image: sample values: bac- Bacteria, prop- Properties]
***Image shows sample values: bac- Bacteria, prop- Properties***
I am studying 300 bacteria sequenced from same sample.
They are grouped in 7 groups having varying number of members. e.g. some group has only 2 while some group has 200.
I am comparing the gene properties of those groups. e.g. number of genes doing some required function.
How to normalize these properties (observations are values ranging from 1 to 100) for such uneven group sizes for proper comparison (similarity or difference) with statistical significance.

> EDIT:
>   I just want to compare which properties are significantly high or low in a particular group. But due to uneven group sizes I can see the values are gonna be high in larger groups while values are low for small groups.
>   The values from a group of 2 members may have values like 2, 4, or any small number and for groups of 100 or more the values will cross 50 to 100.
>   So may I simply divide the values with number of members of the group? or there is any better method.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as unclear because it's unclear if the question is asking about how to test  for normality or how to adjust for disparate group sizes.

Comment: I see nothing in it that hints at testing for normality. The author just wants to know how to compare the counts when the group sizes are so different.

Comment: I can't see that "normalize" is a reference to the Gaussian distribution. But on the other hand, it's not clear what alternative meaning of "normalize" might be intended. I think the answer to this question is "you can analyze the frequencies as they are - the fact they are so disparate does not mean you are unable to perform a hypothesis test." But since the OP has not made clear which hypothesis they are intending to test ("are the results statistically significant" is not a testable statement without clarification!) I think this question will only be answerable after an edit.

Answer (score -3):

You should establish a hypothesis test about normality than test wheter they've come normal distribution or not. You can use `ks.test()` in R;

```
  x <- rnorm(50)
  y <- runif(30)
  ks.test(x, y)

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x and y
D = 0.46, p-value = 0.0004387
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

If you reject null hypothesis which means two population comes from different distribution. There is a few things you can do;

1. Mathematical transformation(commonly used logaritmic transformation).
2. Increase sample size. This refers [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).
3. Nonparametric tests. Applying in R can be found [this](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/nonparametric.html) link.

Comment: How does this address the OP's question about how to rescale the data to be comparable between groups with dramatically different counts?

Comment: He can compare means after transforming(if the group doesn't come normal distribution) with t-test which has no assumptions but normality.

Comment: The data and problem are not well explained but the data look like counts in a cross-classification. If so, this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Although this appears to be both wrong & irrelevant, it was clearly intended as an answer to the question. I think it should stay.

Comment: I agree with @gung for which reason I have downvoted. I think the underlying confusion here is the OP's use of the word "normalize".

Comment: I think, I have confused about problem. Also agree with @gung. Question can be deleted or moved. But what I have said is necessary also this question.